# If $\det(AB-BA) = 0$ and $A^2 + B^2 = 0_n$, then show that $n$ is even.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A,B ∈ M_n(\Bbb R)$. Suppose that 
$A^2 + B^2 = 0_n$ and $\det( AB - BA ) =0$. Show that $n$ is even.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, i'm newbie. So i don't know how to code. I tried : $A^2 + B^2 = (A-iB)(A+iB)$ . But seem like it not work 

Comment: That's ok. For next time, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick reference on how to format mathematics on this site. But back to the question: What have you tried? What do you know about determinants that you think may come in handy?

Comment: Det =0 so AB-BA is not invertible. Am i miss understanding your question? Cause my English also very bad ,hi!

Comment: If the statement holds and if $A$ and $B$ are matrices satisfying the conditions, then so are $A’=\begin{bmatrix}A &0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B’=\begin{bmatrix}B & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, but they are in odd dimension. So you’re likely missing a hypothesis, eg that $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

Answer (score 2):

A simple counterexample is $A=B=0$ for any odd value of $n$.

On the other hand, if either $A$ or $B$ is invertible, then there is a very simple proof.

$A^2=-B^2$ therefore
$|A^2|=|-B^2|$ and so
$|A|^2=(-1)^n|B|^2$.

Then $(-1)^n$ is positive and so $n$ is even.

Comment: Sorry but i'm pretty sure that my example not mention to A,B is invertible or not, can you help me furthermore? (Sorry my english quiet bad ☹️ )

Comment: Since $A=B=0$ is a simple counterexample there has to be some other condition.